Optimally sampling edge weights on a graph
I am working on some network problems where we do not know the underlying edge weights on the network precisely. All we know is that for a (directed) edge $(u,v)$ in the network, the weight $w(u,v) \in [l_{uv}, h_{uv}]$. We are allowed to sample say $K$ edges to know the weights precisely. We then solve a network optimization problem, say, finding the minimum weight path between two vertices $s$ and $t$. Naturally, since we do not know the true edge weights for all edges in our graph, we use the upper end of the range, $h_{uv}$ to obtain the worst-case minimum weight path.
I want to find the way to optimally sample the $K$ true edge weights such that the solution to the worst-case optimization problem is as close as possible to the true optimal solution with the true edge weights. Are there any related problems to this? Any complexity results?

The problem cannot be solved even in principle because the true edge weights are given (so the value of the objective function cannot be computed for any candidate solution).  Can you formulate an objective function you want to minimize, such that the objective function can be computed solely based on the information provided in the input?  A starting point would be to try to formulate a well-defined problem in the special case where $K=0$.

To give an example of the ambiguity, suppose $K=0$.  Would you rather have a path whose total weight is known to be in the range $[10,20]$, or a path whose total weight is known to be in the range $[14,16]$?  (The true edge weights might make the true cost of the paths be 20,14 respectively; or it might make them be 10,16 respectively; so there is no way to decide which path is better.)
